# Authentication with crypt function via File in C (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c, linux, encryption, cryptography, password-encryption

i have the bellow code , and i am trying first of all in case 1 : Register a new password and write it into a file , this works , the problem that i have is in case 2 : where i am trying to make user give a password to crypt it via crypt function and then authenticate it with  all crypted passwords in previous file. But when i am compiling this i am getting an error "Segmentation Fault".In my opinion the problem would be in log_password and the transformation to crypted message. Any help would be great.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


int
main(void)
{

FILE *f=fopen("shadow.txt","a+");  

  char * line=NULL;
  unsigned long seed[2];
  char *log_password,salt[] = "$1$........";
  const char *const seedchars =
    "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST"
    "UVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";



  char *password,*pass;
  int i,ans;

  /* Generate a (not very) random seed.
     You should do it better than this... */
  seed[0] = time(NULL);
  seed[1] = getpid() ^ (seed[0] >> 14 & 0x30000);

  /* Turn it into printable characters from ‘seedchars’. */
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    salt[3+i] = seedchars[(seed[i/5] >> (i%5)*6) & 0x3f];


  printf("Press 1 for Register.\n");
  printf("Press 2 for Login.\n");
  printf("Press 3 for Exit.\n");
  scanf("%d",&ans);
  switch(ans)
  {
    case 1: 

            password = crypt(getpass("Password:"), salt);
            fprintf(f,"%s \n",password);
            printf("Succesfull Register in file\n");
            fclose(f);
            break;


    case 2: 


            fgets(pass,34,f);
            log_password =  crypt(getpass("Login Password:"), pass);
            int ok;
            ok = strcmp (log_password, pass) == 0;
            puts(ok ? "Access granted." : "Access denied.");
            return ok ? 0 : 1;
            break;

    case 3: 
            printf("Bye\n");
            exit(1);
            break;

    default: 
            printf("Try Again.\n");
            break;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you should deal with every warning before wondering why it crashes.

Comment: ...start with the first one first. And once *you don't get any warnings* and it still doesn't work - come back again and we will look further.

Comment: The first warning already is a huge red flag. Without having a closer look, the location of your `#define _GNU_SOURCE` looks suspicious. `_GNU_SOURCE` is a *feature test macro* for the GNU C library making available functions and features that are only implemented on a GNU system. For this to have any effect, it must be defined **before** any headers are included.

Comment: for the bigger picture, are you sure you want to build some hown-brewn authentication using `crypt()`? If you want to authenticate against the system's user db, have a look at `PAM`. In any case, there are much better, more secure ways for hashing passwords.

Comment: @FelixPalmen i have to do it , with crypt.

Comment: i fixed some warnings but have same problem @FelixPalmen

Comment: i fixed some warnings but have same problem @WeatherVane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that i forget to allocate memory...

```
#define pass_size 1000
 pass=calloc(pass_size,sizeof(char));
```